# HTML Display name but append email on copy

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

Is this possible to do. Display a comma separated list of names but when you copy, it automatically appends their emails.

e.g.

copied - "John Doe"
pasted - "John Doe "

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying text to the clipboard programmatically is not made easy, because it would be particularly easy to abuse.

Your best bet is to use a javascript library like this: https://clipboardjs.com/

You know what's best for your users but it's not always a great experience to expect to copy something, and actually get something else.